# USB eHCI host driver compatible with xHCI controller?

Tags: usb, host

I have an xHCI USB host controller connected to processor with an OS that has only eHCI host driver support. Does the eHCI driver support/compatible with xHCI controller. Only USB2.0 devices are required to be connected to the host. USB3.0 device support is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Its completely impossible as there is a huge difference between the EHCI and XHCI interface. The whole way of USB transfers have changed. The data structures changed. Only Register interface remained compatible.
Its simply impossible. I am guessing by now you already know the answer.